# How much distance did the magic carpet ride cover?

Tags: aladdin

How far did Aladdin and Jasmine travel on their magic carpet ride in Aladdin (1992)?

We can suppose that Agrabah is really Baghdad.  They pass by the pyramids and the sphinx, pass by some Greek-looking architecture, and end up in China.  Besides Giza, are there any other specific locations that appear in the film which we could use to nail down their itinerary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the scene: *A Whole New World* & *Aladdin and Jasmine's firs kiss* you'll see them travel to the next cities:

**In this order**:

- Start in Bagdad (Agrabah)
- First city: Caïro
- Second city: Athene (Olympus)
- Third city: China
- Back to Bagdad (Agrabah)

**So in miles**:

- From Bagdad to Caïro it's: 804.377 miles.
- From Caïro to Athene's it's: 856.443 miles.
- From Athene to China it's: 5968.128 miles.
- From China back to Bagdad it's: 3357.658 miles.

Total of 9325,786 miles, which is 15008.40 km.
So as you say it would be over a time of ' +- 8 hours'. They would fly at a speed of **1876.05 km per hour**.

Then again Andrew Martin his answer is correct too, we are never sure of what places they visited and if you look at the last scene where Aladdin kisses Jasmine, they stayed in China for '**X**' amount of time. So the time above is only calculated for if they would fly all night without stopping. Andrew's right, it's an animated, fun film for a reason! :)

Comment: It is a fun film, and calculating average ground speed for a hypothetical trip is part of the fun :-)

Comment: If you wanted to get a better handle on speed ranges then you might want to factor in timezones and what speeds are needed to start in Agrabah hit the other cites, go to China (when still dark) and return to Agrabah. That should give you a min/max. Of course the carpet could use the same magic that Santa uses to visit all the homes in the world in one very busy night....

Comment: @Erik I'm not stopping you :D

Comment: Video links are dead.

Comment: The script explicitly states that they're at the Forbidden City in China. I'm not even going to point out that it wasn't built until thousands of years after the Sphinx.

Answer (score 6):

**We don't know**.

I assume you are referring to *[Disney's Aladdin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aladdin_(1992_Disney_film))*. The scene in question is a montage. We're not shown *every* place they went to, and the passage of time between the areas is thus very difficult to gauge.

[MoviePilot](http://moviepilot.com/posts/2152576) did remark:

> While Aladdin and Jasmine take their romantic ride together they
>   somehow manage to travel from Cairo to Athens in under one second.
>   That's around 1100 kilometers!! Travelling that far at such speed
>   would apply around 99 million newtons of force!
>
> So...even if Aladdin and Jasmine could manage to hold onto the carpet,
>   their skin should have been torn from their bones. Hmm, suddenly
>   that's not sounding so romantic...

So, it's basically impossible to gauge their total distance travelled *and* their overall ground speed (which, as the analysis above shows, is certainly Physics-defying).

Ultimately it's an animated, fun film and this is magic - so the realism was irrelevant to Disney and wasn't focussed on.

Comment: Sound like a Gothic scene.

Comment: I don't follow why it's impossible to calculate minimum average ground speed.  If we calculate a minimum distance traveled based on the landmarks, and a maximum flight time, then we get a minimum average ground speed.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Two problems: we don't know all the distance they travelled (as it was a montage) and we don't know how long they flew for (other than *very* rough estimates).

Comment: I feel like I'm talking to a brick wall here.  Did you read the part where I said "minimum"?  I don't want to repeat what I just wrote, but the word "minimum" is kind of important, and it seems like you're glossing over it.  Help me out here.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Well, it's not exactly hard to work out, is it? As stated in the answer, they traveled from Cairo to Athens, 1100km, in 1 second. So their minimum speed is 1100km/s. Anything more accurate is impossible to gauge, for obvious reasons.

Comment: @AndrewMartin The original question presupposes a total time in flight of 8 hours. The scene/song in the film was significantly shorter than eight hours. The known order and known locations are given in the film. That information, combined with the presupposed eight hour flight time, can be used to calculate the desired value. Discarding the presupposed flight time (as you insist on) is attempting to redefine the question.

Comment: @T.J.L.: Sorry, but why on earth are we presupposing an eight hour flight time? That's not in the film. I mean, this makes it sound like this question ought to be asked over at the Physics SE. This isn't really based off the film anymore, it's just a request for help in a basic Maths problem. If we presuppose different times, we'll get different results, obviously! As we don't know the time, how is the answer to this anything other than "We don't know".

Comment: @AndrewMartin You should be presupposing an eight hour flight time, because that's the context provided in the original question If you're not using the _parameters_ of the poster's question, then you're _not answering_ the poster's question. If you believe the question is invalid or inappropriate, that's what a vote-to-close is for.

Comment: @T.J.L.: Read the question again. It *doesn't* presuppose it. It merely says: *Perhaps they could be in flight for eight hours total that night*. That's certainly not a definitive starting point. No parameters are stated at all! No, all we have to go on is a montage which is obviously unclear. But look, this is an animated film and we really, *really* don't know. People can upvote whatever they want, but it seems pointless to continue arguing about this. Hopefully the other answer gives the OP what they want.

Comment: @AndrewMartin I think it does presuppose it, even if it's not worded rigidly. However, I also agree with your point that it's a basic mathematics question. It fits the criteria of "unimportant trivia that does not add to the understanding or appreciation of a title", which is defined as a bad question in the tour. I've flagged it. My point for you, subtly, was perhaps you're being too harsh on a low rep user (despite the fact that he's a very high rep elsewhere on the network, because branching out a bit is a good thing).

Comment: @T.J.L.: If this were a basic mathematics question, I suppose I could have just solved it myself.  However, I was primarily looking for clues to the locations where they traveled, e.g., I can recognize Giza, but I'm not sure what other locations might have been shown.  This seems like a concrete, non-mathematical question to me.  And if it doesn't add to your appreciation of the movie, then I'm fine with appreciating movies in different ways, but that seems like a really subjective justification for flagging this particular question.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: So then why didn't you just ask "where did they travel to on the carpet?". Look, we've all argued and discussed this enough. I'm glad you got an answer that helped you, let's leave it at that.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I agree with Andrew, here. This is kind of two questions. One of them is appropriate, "What are the locations shown in the carpet ride scene?" I can definitely see how that would contribute to somebody's understanding or appreciation of the movie. The other question, "How fast did they travel?" is really a separate question and inappropriate, because as people discussed, it's a fantasy montage for a musical number. The inappropriateness of the math bit spoils the whole question.

Comment: @AndrewMartin: I suppose the question title was worded poorly, but the first line was "How far..." and the second paragraph was an expansion on that same point, and the third paragraph was a follow-up question which could only be answered once we knew "how far".  Maybe I'll be more explicit next time I ask a question, I'm far more used to answering questions than asking them.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: No worries, glad you got your answer. Let's not get too stressed over this :)

Comment: @T.J.L.: I appreciate that it takes a while to express questions exactly, and it takes a while to understand the community standards of a new site.  I've edited the question to remove the part about speed, since it was just an unimportant / trivial followup question to the main question.  In the future, if you think that part of the question is inappropriate, I would be more than happy to just edit it out of the question altogether, or delete the question myself.

Answer (score 1):

The [film script](https://assets.scriptslug.com/live/pdf/scripts/aladdin-1992.pdf) makes it abundantly clear that they went to *various destinations*, including those that we see, as well as some that we don't.

> In a romantic, picturesque MUSICAL MONTAGE we follow Aladdin
> and Jasmine as the Carpet takes them on a magical tour.
> The Carpet takes them down, amongst a herd of running horses.
> Aladdin turns it into a race, urging the carpet ahead. Jasmine
> cheers when they pull ahead of the lead horse--then strokes the
> surprised horse's mane, waves 'bye-bye' to it.
> They sweep past the pyramids, around the Sphinx. A worker is
> startled by the Carpet; his hammer blow misses the chisel, and
> the Sphinx's nose crumbles away.
> They cruise past Grecian temples, over a still pond. The Carpet
> whips quickly through the tree branches--creates a cascade of
> falling blossoms. Then moves slowly through the cascade, near
> to the water. Jasmine trails a hand on the surface; the Carpet
> flies an intricate pattern--the wake left by Jasmine's trailing
> hand makes a beautiful design.

> The carpet follows the terrain of the land, rising up over a hill-- and before them is the Great Wall of China. They both  look at it in shared wonder.
>
> EXT. FORBIDDEN CITY - NIGHT
>
> Aladdin and Jasmine are perched atop a building against a
> background of twinkling stars. The Carpet sits away from them,
> nearer to the roof's edge, dangling its feet, applauding the--FIREWORKS from a street festival. MUSIC can be heard.

Given the significant distances, thousands of miles, between these places, and utterly ignoring the anachronism involved, we can conclude that they traveled *a magical route over a magical timescale.*

Answer (score -2):

I see this montage as more of the young couple's infatuation with one another as they imagine all the places they will go and see together. Both of them have more than likely spent their whole life in Agrabah and "neighboring areas" and never really had the opportunity to go anywhere else. So in their reality they probably only really flew around the city.

Comment: Can you offer any proof or evidence to back up this theory?

Comment: This script makes it pretty clear that they went to these actual places.